# Method that converts string to Upper Case

Tags: c++, c++11

Hey guys so here is my code. I want to convert string to upperCase i.e "Hello World" to "HELLO WORLD". But i am getting this error, have no idea what this is. New to C++ :p

Here is what the prof asked me to do: 
"The function upConvert is to turn a C++ string of ascii characters into a dynamically allocated character array (old-style C-string) of appropriate size. The character array must have the same ascii characters as the string except all lower case characters turned into upper case."

```
char* upConvert(const string& s ){

for(unsigned int l = 0; l < s.length(); l++)
{
    s[l] = toupper(s[l]);
}
```

the error i am getting:

```
read-only variable is not assignable
    s[l] = toupper(s[l]);
```

Comment: Where is the character array that's required by the assignment?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing `s` into `upConvert` as a const reference, so it can't be changed.  I'd say remove the `const`, but this solution does not look like what the prof is asking for, either.

Answer (score 1):

Well i'm going to attempt to not give you the code answer, but this is a way to go about it...

1. Allocate a char array correctly and remember null termination
2. Look into **strcpy** as a way of doing a conversion
3. Then for converting to upper case i'd take a look at iterating
   through your char array and converting character by character using
   **toupper()**.

Check this out: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: Hope i didn't give too much. Was hoping to allow you to connect the dots. :P

Comment: There's no need for `strcpy` if the string has to be iterated in full anyway - iteration and writing to the array can be combined into a single loop